# Flutter smart-code generation shortcut in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

when I select a widget say a Text widget in android studio, I hit on alt and enter to generate a code. For example, you can wrap a widget inside a column with this combination but in my case, this combination suggests me things like : generate getter and setter or toString() method which definitely come from java. Now you might say, you have to change your key binding then but that is the problem, on keyboard shortcuts section, I see only one section where I can assign a combination. But then this happens where I only get code suggestions for java. How could I possibly change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found the solution, when you check the keyboard shortcuts, you gotta find show context actions and assign a key binding to it, then it is fixed.